# Where can I see the source code of malloc() or any library function in my windows(xp) PC?

Tags: c

I know that, when we call any library function in our source code, The function definitions will be loaded into RAM (assuming dynamic linking) at run time.
But where exactly the definitions of library functions stored.

If they are not in .c format, how they are stored??

Comment: `The function definitions will be loaded into RAM`..well, it's a bit more complex that in sounds here. :-) Anyway, try looking into the corresponding library source code.

Comment: For statically linked libraries you can fine the implementation in disassemble listing,which a very time consuming task and needs a lots of handwork which is not worth of it.This task is near to impossible.

Comment: You have to be specific about the compiler you use if you want a "look here" answer.  There is rarely much to see, memory management is an OS duty on Windows so malloc() doesn't do anything more than call HeapAlloc().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get any function definition, you need to check the source code [That was obvious].

To get the function definitions which are part of a library, [ex - `glibc`], you've to get the source code of the library and browse through that. Usually, the library source codes, [.c format, if you mean] will be compiled to produce a library, either

- static [usually, noted by `.a`]
- dynamic [Usually, noted by `.so`, *shared object*]

to be linked with some source code to produce the final binary.

So, yes, they are in .c format (least, *human readable* format, I better say) which you can browse through.

Note: An [online browsable](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/glibc/master/files) version of glibc.

<sup>P.S - Sorry, if my answer is biased towards linux *implementations* however, it is still valid for `windows(xp) PC`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example Windows implementation of `malloc` [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-1765/libbanshee/engine/malloc.c). On Windows, it's mostly a wrapper for WinAPI functions such as `HeapAlloc`. You can find other implementations of this and other functions in various opensource libraries.

Note that on Windows, a compiler doesn't have to provide implementations for the standard C functions, as they are all available in `msvcrt.dll`. You can't get the source code of these implementations, but you can still disassemble the DLL and look at the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

The header file contain the definition. Inside the header file named alloc.h, we can find that header file in the folder include. you have to specify the environment you are using.it is saved with extention. .h